# Is Brain Sync music effective in increasing cognitive functioning?

Tags: neuroscience, intelligence, hearing, meditation

From [the website](http://www.brainsync.com/):

> BRAIN SYNC meditation CDs and guided imagery techniques are proven to
>   significantly improve mental performance. In two decades, nearly 3
>   million Brain Sync users have experienced the powerful benefits of
>   deep meditation to accelerate healing, learning, recovery and personal
>   growth. Brain Sync brainwave technology blends advanced meditation
>   techniques with harmonically layered binaural beat frequencies.

**Is there scientific support for Brain Sync music in improving cognitive functioning?**